# HTML to Javascript to PHP. Is this dangerous?

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

I want to get a PHP variable from Javascript. so I use help from HTML

```
<input type="text" value="" name="number1"id="number"style="display:none;">
```

And then I give the value from Javascript

```
 var c = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 5)).toString();

 document.getElementById("number").value = c;
```

And finally take it in PHP

```
$number =$_POST["number1"];
```

Is this dangerous and have any bug possibilities? Thank you

Comment: Yes it's fine. Just do serverside validations. Any data from clientside is dangerous. You can use `<input type="hidden">` instead of `display:none;` though.

Comment: Depends how you're storing & presenting the user input. If storing, SQL Injections are a possibility, if presenting XSS Injection is a possibility.

Comment: @Faisal. never heard about that type of input. New knowledge for me :)

Comment: @Darren. this kind of code is never perfectly safe, isnt it ? I will check about those injections then

Comment: Structure your document with HTML. Validate only little things (length of strings for example) with JS and send a request to certain files. With PHP validate all the data and send response to your JS if all its OK or no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code could be safe, it depends on what you do with the data you receive.

Always keep in mind that you may never trust the user.
You could use if-statements to check to see if the input from the user is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Validate in PHP is much easier for you.

> See [PHP 5 Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp) at W3Schools

Comment: it's all about the javascript code that made me use this kind of way. But I'll check that references. thank you

Comment: If your want to input, don't sanitize the html/risky scripts. Just sanitize them on output. But if you're using database, just sanitize some sql injections in the input, not output.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code. You can use php inside javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jvalue = 'this is javascript value';
  <?php $abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"?>   
</script>

<?php echo  'php_'.$abc;?>
```